# forgot password temporary page php

Tags: php

As i have it right now, any user could type an email on forgot.php page and if the email exists, the user assigned to that email's password would be changed.  How would i change my code so that it sends a link to the users email which directs to a temporary page where they change their password.  I know how to do a change password script but how do i create a link to a temporary page?

forgot.php

```
echo "<div id='sign-parent-container'>
        <div class='form-title'>Forgotten Username/Password</div>
            <form action='/login' action='post' id='forgot-form'>
                <ul>
                <li>Type the email address you registered with, a link to a temporary page where you can change your password will be sent.</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type='text' name='email' value='Type Registered Email Here' class='signupfield-2' /><li>
                        <li style='display:none;'><span class='error'>This email doesn't exist</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class='form-submit' data-type='forgot'><a>Request Password Change</a>
                <input type='hidden' name='forgot' value='1' /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>";
```

/email

```
          $to = $email;
          $subject = "example - New Password Request.";
          $headers = "From: example.com";
          $server = "http://www.example.com";

          ini_set("SMTP",$server);
          $body="


          Hello $username,\r\r

          Your login details are below;\r\r


          Click the link below to change password:\r
          http://www.exmaple.com/temporarylink
           \n\n



          ";
          //function to send email


          mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: pages doesn't have to be temporary, just pass it a unique id.

Comment: forgot.php?user_id=123&secredt_id=frvkeithje5wch9 store secret_id (generated randomly) and user id in a table, delete it after they visit the page so its available one time only. good idea to store a date to and expire it after an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will want to add another column to your database, such as passwordResetKey
When the user does "forgot my password" and enters their email, do not change the password, set the passwordResetKey as a randomly generated value.
Email the email address with a link to the reset page with the email adderss and key
such as forgot.php?email=example@example.org&key=hsdf39SD

Once the user changes the password reset the forgotPasswordKey field to null.

You may also want to add a date field so that the password reset key is only valid for 24 hours or so.